# How to mimic Wordpress "Widget" drag & drop behavior?

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, widget, jquery-ui-sortable

I need to mimic Wordpress "Widget" drag & drop behavior. [jQuery UI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#portlets) can do it but not the same way as WP.

I can drag & drop now but the dropped element is removed from the source. That's not what I expected.

Let's say I have two `<ul>` A and B. I drag an item of A and drop it to B and I expect the item stay within A, not to be removed from it.

Any idea? I really appreciate your helps!

Comment: Can you add some sample code showing what you've tried and what doesn't work?

Comment: I won't post the sample code here bcoz it's pretty long and you can view it directly from jQuery demos page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [jQuery Draggable Sortable demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable)

If you want the draggable item to remain in the first list as well look you need to set 'helper' to 'clone'

ie.

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
  connectToSortable: "#sortable",
  helper: "clone",
  revert: "invalid"
});
```